# Click event not updating global variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-listener

I have a website with 2 pages. In the first page (landing page), I have this clickable element:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="arrest-data" onclick="changeDisp()>
    <div class="box-part text-center"> <i class="fa-solid fa-3x fa-handcuffs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Arrest Data</h3>
      </div>
     <div class="text"> <span>Crime data and other crime statistics</span> </div> <a href="#" class="get-data">GET DATA</a>
</div>
```

I want to change the value of a global variable when that clickable element is clicked:

```
var disp = 0;
function changeDisp(){
    disp = 120
    console.log(disp)   
}
```

So this works and it prints `120`.

The problem is that the value of disp doesn't change globally.For example, on the second page, there's another dropdown menu:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row dropdowns">
  <div class="col-4">
    <select id="categoryDropdown">
      <option value="All">All Topics</option>
      <option value="Category: Arrest Data">Arrest Data</option>
      <option value="Category: Use of Force">Use of Force</option>
      <option value="Category: Human Trafficking">Human Trafficking</option>
      <option value="Category: Treatment and Diversion">Treatment and Diversion</option>
      <option value="Category: Drug and Overdose Data">Drug and Overdose Data</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And when I test to see if the global variable is now 120 with this function:

```
$('.container').on("change", 'select', function() {
    console.log(disp)
});
```

It still prints 0!

What am I doing wrong here?  I want the value to change globally with the on-click event, and it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: Are you setting a variable on one page and expecting it to be there on another page?

Comment: Yes, indeed I am, that's my use-case.  How can I accomplish this?  HTML files for both pages include the same <script> tag that links to my main.js file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read and use values between separate pages you could use something like **localStorage** to store your values and then read from it when needed.

Ref: [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

See the implementation below:

```js
// Setter function
function setDisp(value) {
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    localStorage.setItem('disp', Number(value));
  }
}

// Getter function
function getDisp(defaultValue = 0) {
  let localStorageValue = localStorage.getItem('disp');
  return !!localStorageValue 
    ? Number(localStorageValue)
    : defaultValue;
}

let dispBeforeChange = getDisp();
console.log(`dispBeforeChange = ${dispBeforeChange}`);

// Changing the value of 'disp' to 120
setDisp(120)

let dispAfterChange = getDisp();
console.log(`dispAfterChange = ${dispAfterChange}`);
```